# Animation doesn't fade in on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a hover effect for my sidebar. But for some reason the the elements I have inside the sidebar doesn't fade in if I hover on it too much. 
You can see the working beta version here:

http://www.nk.thnk.org/

```
$('#sidebar').stop().animate({ 'width': '40px'}, 500);
$('#sidebar .icon').stop().fadeIn(0);
$('#sidebar #logo').stop().fadeOut(0);
$('#sidebar #nav').stop().fadeOut(0);
$('#sidebar .quote').stop().fadeOut(0);
$('#sidebar .branding').stop().fadeOut(0);

// sidebar
$('#sidebar').hover(function(){
    $('#sidebar').stop().animate({ 'width': '200px'}, 500);
    $('#sidebar .icon').stop().fadeOut();
    $('#sidebar #logo').stop().fadeIn();
    $('#sidebar #nav').stop().fadeIn();
    $('#sidebar .quote').stop().fadeIn();
    $('#sidebar .branding').stop().fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $('#sidebar').stop().animate({ 'width': '40px'}, 500);
    $('#sidebar .icon').stop().fadeIn(function(){ $(this).removeClass('flipped');});
    $('#sidebar #logo').stop().fadeOut();
    $('#sidebar #nav').stop().fadeOut();
    $('#sidebar .quote').stop().fadeOut();
    $('#sidebar .branding').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Try `.stop(true, true)`

Comment: You **really** should cache your jQuery variables, every time you call `$('#sidebar')` you are performing a potentially expensive DOM lookup. Try `var $sidebar = $('#sidebar');` then you can use: `$sidebar.find('.nav')..` etc.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thanks man the true true parameters works!
Really appreciate you answer.

Comment: @RobM Ow I didn't knew it works like this. Thanks for this great tip I'll use it in my future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fade in, the element must be considered as `:hidden`. So if you hover while it is fading out, jQuery will not fadeIn since the element is visible.

There is 2 solutions. The first one is to use `.stop(true, true)`. Using true as argument mean *"clear queue and jump to end"* and the element will be hidden before the `fadeIn()`.

But the solution i like the most is to use `fadeTo()` :

```
 $(el).fadeTo('slow', 0); //Hide element
 $(el).fadeTo('slow', 1); //Show element
```

## Bonus

Here an more readable code for you :

```
var $sidebar = $('#sidebar'),
    $icons = $sidebar.find('.icon'),
    $otherObj = $sidebar.find('#logo, #nav, .quote, .branding')

$('#sidebar').hover(function(){
    $sidebar.stop().animate({ 'width': '200px'}, 500)
    $icons.stop().fadeOut()
    $otherObj.stop().fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $sidebar.stop().animate({ 'width': '40px'}, 500)
    $icons.stop().fadeIn().done(function(){ $(this).removeClass('flipped');})
    $otherObj.stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thanks the second method is indeed nicer.